# Form post best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing my first ASP.NET MVC 4 application and am struggling to work out whether what I have done is either a good way of doing it, overkill or just plain stupid.

I know there are a million ways to do things but just looking for some best practice guidance.

Basically my Index view renders a simple form, on POST I am creating a PDF, storing it in the session and the ViewBag and passing it off to the Confirm action. All the Confirm action is used for is displaying a view (Confirm.cshtml).

Can anyone guide me here?

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {

        // Create PDF
        var doc = new Document();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));
        doc.Close();

        byte[] docData = memoryStream.GetBuffer(); // get the generated PDF as raw data

        // create id and store data in Session
        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Session[id] = docData;

        // store the id in ViewBag
        ViewBag.id = id;

        return View("Confirm");
    }

    // Handles the /Home/Confirm view
    public ActionResult Confirm()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Download(string id)
    {
        var docData = (byte[]) Session[id];

        if (docData == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        Session[id] = null;

        return File(docData, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    }

}
```

**View**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Confirm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="/Home/Download?id=@ViewBag.id">Download PDF</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want code review or what do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a MVC point of view:

Using ViewModels are a good practice to get into, take a look at this tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/nerddinner/use-viewdata-and-implement-viewmodel-classes

**Some Advantages:**

The view model isolates the view from the model classes and allows the model to evolve independently of the view.

This enables type-safety, compile-time checking, and editor intellisense within view templates.

Security, if you expose objects straight out of an ORM to a View, properties like IsAdmin may be manipulated, using View Models you can restrict this.

**Something I would change in the Index Post Action**

```
return View("Confirm");
```

To:

```
return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
```

Becuase:

Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a web development design pattern that prevents some duplicate form submissions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Another good reason to use ViewModels, you can redirect and pass a model as a parameter eg return RedirectToAction("Confirm", Model); As an alternative similar to the ViewBag is TempData["key"] this will persist until the http request and will be deleted automaticaly after this. The syntax is like ViewData. More Info: http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but sounds exactly what I need will accept your answer. Thanks!